# Does the function name on createServerHandler necessarily have to be a global function in the same script in which createServerHandler is called?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a library UI class in which I am setting a serverHandler.  I'd like the serverHandler function name to be a method name instead of a global function. (e.g. 'this.someMethod').  However this does not seem to work.  How can I specify a methodName for the funcString argument of the server eventhandler? (app.createServerHandler(funcString))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately server handlers can only reference global functions.